# Stored procedure not returning result in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have been in this problem since ages, tried all verified methods but problem didn't solve. I am calling MySQL stored procedure thru CI Model to get the result. But query result not returning result not even showing any error. Below is the code:

## Controller

```
function get_leads()
{
    $maxlimit = 10;
    $this->data["leads"] = $this->reports_model->calling_sp($maxlimit);
    $this->load->view('reports/get_leads', $this->data);
}
```

## Model

```
 function calling_sp($id$maxlimit) {
    $query = $this->db->query("CALL sp_test($maxlimit)");
    return $query->result();    
 }
```

In the above code "return $query->result();" line is not working not even showing any error message. 
It is not even showing the number of records if I try "$query->num_rows()" to check. In MySQL stored procedure is working fine.

## Here is stored proc

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
 IN `maxlimit` INT
 )
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 CONTAINS SQL
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT ''
 BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM leads
    WHERE id < maxlimit;
 END
```

Please guide me where I am making mistake or anything important I may be missing in codeigniter config. ?

Error log file showing this message only: 
"Error --> Call to a member function result() on boolean"

Comment: Did you debug what contain $query->result()?

Comment: I used print_r() but it display nothing there is some error which is also not being shown on page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the database name to the stored procedure. For example, if your database is named `mydb`, then you must change the query line in your model to this:

`$query = $this->db->query("CALL mydb.sp_test($maxlimit)");`